# No Matching <VirtualHost> Error When Starting Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I keep getting an error when trying to start Apache:

```
</VirtualHost> without matching <VirtualHost> section
```

...referring to line 4 of the Apache config file listed below:

```
<VirtualHost 74.117.238.120:80>
   ServerName www.mydomain.biz    
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 74.117.238.120:80>
   ServerName codejerk.mydomain.biz   
   DocumentRoot /var/www/codejerk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 74.117.238.120:80>
   ServerName www.mydomain.tk   
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 74.117.238.120:80>
   ServerName codejerk.mydomain.tk
   DocumentRoot /var/www/codejerk
</VirtualHost>
```

The 'Listen' and 'NameVirtualHost' directives are in the file that calls this one:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 74.117.238.120:80
```

This is driving me nuts-- clearly each VirtualHost block has an opening and closing tag...

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As shown in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html try interchanging the `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` lines.

Comment: I've already tried that-- no luck!

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when you save vHost-files in PC/Windows format with '\r\n' instead of unix format '\n'.
Saving these files again in unix format solves the problem.

Additionally it is required to remove the Byte Order Mark (BOM), if existing.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Debugging this is really almost impossible to solve in my case actually. 

I actually just copied/pasted a configuration file without paying attention to the source format. Aha time, I didn't really know that this \r\n can escape the gedit editor.

Comment: BOM is an issue for apache2. \r\n is NOT an issue (it would be fun than a HTTP server does not handle \r\n which is what HTTP requires :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by merging the contents of apache2/sites-available/default and /apache2/ports.conf into apache2/apache2.conf and removing the lines that were including these files.

Apparently something was out of whack with the order in which these other files were being included.

Answer (score 0):

apache2 displays this weird message when your configuration file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Most tools will hide/ignore the BOM, but you can easily detect it using command `file`:

```
% file /etc/apache2/conf-available/maxclients.conf 
/etc/apache2/conf-available/maxclients.conf: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```